# Do I need a transit visa in JFK?

Tags: transit

I'm Nigerian, passing through JFK on EgyptAir on my way to Guyana. I do not plan to leave the airport, and the connecting is with another airline (BW). I want to know if it is possible without a transit visa.

Comment: See the linked duplicate, but the short answer is yes you need a visa, unless you have another citizenship or US permanent residency or some other means to enter the US.

Comment: You need a Transit visa (type C1)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a transit in the US. Everyone is admitted at their first port of entry; which means that you must be eligible to enter the US in order to switch flights.